# Question does not make sense anymore since software update

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, outdated-information, outdated-answer

I recently asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73355349/8186898) that basically asks "why can't I do this in TypeScript?" but since the merge of [#50666](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/50666) the question doesn't make sense anymore because what I ask to do can actually be achieved in the latest TypeScript version.

[question code that doesn't work in typescript@4.8.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2&ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=27#code/MYewdgzgLgBGIBMCmBJCBVCSA2SIRgF4YAKeZALhgFcwBreAdzAEoiA+AKBjkSRgCEhYmGrZsMAGSTuMKAE8ADkhAAzXsiLCYAIhAAjAFZJgUHVJk8dC5eYCWYDf2mybK9eSQA6N1uI7oACcHAHNzFx5PHyV+YX8AKQBlAA0AFSQADzMAbiA) (latest version when asking the question)

[question code that works now](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20220920#code/MYewdgzgLgBGIBMCmBJCBVCSA2SIRgF4YAKeZALhgFcwBreAdzAEoiA+AKBjkSRgCEhYmGrZsMAGSTuMKAE8ADkhAAzXsiLCYAIhAAjAFZJgUHVJk8dC5eYCWYDf2mybK9eSQA6N1uI7oACcHAHNzFx5PHyV+YX8AKQBlAA0AFSQADzMAbiA) (if the link is dead, select the "nightly" version to get the latest ts version)

This makes the question not really useful and the answers even less, but I can't find a corresponding close cause. What should I do?

Comment: Usually I see people write answers that say it's now possible - e.g. "as of merge 50666, this is possible using x new feature." - with appropriate links.

Comment: "*This makes the question not really useful and the answers even less*" Not even to people who use an older version of TypeScript?

Comment: Funny how things change depending on which shoes you're in. I would argue this makes the question and answer *more* valuable. As long as it is clear for which version it is, of course.

Comment: Could you just label it as for the appropriate version or versions of Typescript, much like VLAZ hints at?

Comment: The "software update" you're mentionning is in a nightly, which means that essentially no-one uses that version yet. When the next stable version of Typescript will be released, then maybe your question will become slightly obsolete, but at the moment it absolutely isn't.

Comment: If you were the *answerer* I'd suggest to add a notice to the top of your answer, but since you're not, that would break the author's intent rule.

Comment: History is good. If people can't be bothered to notice that a qa is old, that's their problem.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Leave it.

It made sense when you wrote it, but it doesn't now.  That happens all the time in software.

You could also answer the question by saying that an update fixed this issue.

Comment: There's always some poor sucker maintaining a legacy system where upgrading is not an option.

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/979/).

Answer (score 39):

Edit the question to make the version explicit. This makes it apparent whether the question is relevant for people using a legacy version and having a similar problem.
If you already know a range of versions is affected, consider a loose version constraint:

> This code fails to compile on early 4.8 releases (e.g. 4.8.2):

If regardless you feel the update means the question is of no help for anyone else (e.g. the broken version was yanked or a pre-release, …) then consider the question as **no longer reproducible**.

Answer (score 17):

I would add a separate answer to the question stating that this was an issue which was fixed in version X (with appropriate links or quotes as appropriate).

Amongst other benefits, users still on the old version who find themselves on this question know that a good resolution path would be to upgrade to a fixed version of the library.

You could mark this as the accepted answer as well.